# Can you call an object from a different Sub?

Tags: excel, internet-explorer

I am fairly new to VBA. I have a project that I am working and I need to get the tool to cycle through an excel sheet, and 4 IE pages. I have a Sub routine that opens the IE pages. What I need to do now, after the pages are open, is cycle through them and the excel doc that the code is written in, as well as refreshing the IE pages once focus is moved away from the page. These cycles need to be in 5 second intervals. Here is my sub routine that opens the IE pages. Not too sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub openPendings()
Dim IE1 As Object
Dim IE2 As Object
Dim IE3 As Object
Dim IE4 As Object
Dim IE5 As Object

Set IE1 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set IE2 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set IE3 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set IE4 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set IE5 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE1.navigate "https://www.google.com" 'Pending Issues
apiShowWindow IE1.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
IE2.navigate "https://www.yahoo.com" 'Pending Issues
apiShowWindow IE2.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
IE3.navigate "https://www.ebay.com" 'Pending Issues
apiShowWindow IE3.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
IE4.navigate "https://www.espn.com" 'Pending Issues
apiShowWindow IE4.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
IE5.navigate "http://www.nfl.com" 'Current issues
apiShowWindow IE5.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
End Sub
```

Comment: on focus refresh would not work? or, refreshing excel book not work? Also, source is excel, destination is IE or reverse?

Comment: The source is excel. The excel sheet is a chart that is updated every minute. The IE pages are just for information, and need to cycle so that the chart is visible for 5 seconds, then IE1 is visible for 5 seconds, then IE2 for 5 seconds, etc.. and repeat. Since they are only visible for 5 seconds each, I was going to refresh the IE pages once the focus is no longer on that page. I hope this all makes sense.

Comment: upload more info about your chart sheet and its update code. Upto now, the thing is, your chart contain source info, chart updated every min, IE pages contain these info, but when the refreshing of pages end?

Comment: The chart uses a data connection to get the data for the updates. The IE pages are for visual information, and are not related to the excel chart in any way.